# STL emplace струтктуры с некопируемыми членами

Tags: c++, конструктор, вектор

Имею код:

```
struct A{
    std::atomic<int> atomic{};
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> vector;
    vector.emplace_back();

    return 0;
}
```

И ошибку:

> use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’ 
>   ::new(static_cast(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
>
> use of deleted function ‘std::atomic::atomic(const std::atomic&)

Не могу понять, откуда в этом коде попытки вызова конструктора копирования std::atomic.
Как всё таки `emplace` value с `noncopyable` members?

Comment: можно atomic завернуть в unique_ptr, `std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<int>> _a{ new std::atomic<int>{} };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. При добавлении нового элемента вектор может выделить новый, расширенный, буфер, в который будут копироваться / перемещаться существующие элементы. Соответственно если конструкторы копирования / перемещения не доступны, то этот код работать не будет. Используйте какой-нибудь другой контейнер, который не требует копирования / перемещения существующих элементов.

Comment: Разве `emplace` не строит на месте вызывая конструктор? Откуда там копирование/перемещение?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan Строит. Конструктор копирования / перемещения может вызываться для тех элементов, которые там уже лежат, а не для нового.

Comment: при realloc? А если описать конструктор копирования/перемещения для структуры?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan что значит "описать конструктор"? если бы конструктор был, то оно бы работало, но в std::atomic его нет, точнее он запрещен

Comment: `std::deque` избавлена от этих проблем?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan ну если для struct A их реализовать, то да. Да, при реаллокации. deque не перевыделяет существующие буфера при добавлении в конец, но может делать это в других случаях, например при удалении из середины.